# background gradient color and background image DRYly

Tags: html, css

I have a number of headings and in the background of each I want to show the same gradient color, but a different (non-repeating) background image. I want to avoid duplicating any CSS rules for  the background gradient color or background image position, because they will be the same for each heading. In other words, the only thing I should need to specify for an individual heading is the path to the background image file.

Here's what I have at the moment:

```
<h1 class="banner bgImage img1">background image 1</h1>
<h1 class="banner bgImage img2">background image 2</h1>
<h1 class="banner bgImage img3">background image 3</h1>
<h1 class="banner">heading without background image</h1>

.banner {
    /* For old browsers that don't support gradients */
    background-color: #9FCC1D; 

    /* browser-specific prefixes omitted */
    background-image: linear-gradient(#75A319, #9FCC1D); 
    padding: 7px 7px 7px 15px;
}

/* Specifies position of background image */
.bgImage {
    background-position: 5px 50%, 0 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding-left: 30px;
}

.img1 {
    background-image: url(img1.png"), linear-gradient(#75A319, #9FCC1D);
}

.img2 {
    background-image: url(img2.png"), linear-gradient(#75A319, #9FCC1D);
}

.img3 {
    background-image: url(img3.png"), linear-gradient(#75A319, #9FCC1D);
}
```

There are a couple of problems with this

1. I have to repeat the `linear-gradient` style in each `.imgX` rule
2. It doesn't render correctly in Chrome, which doesn't seem to support a comma-separated list of `background-image` and `background-repeat` properties. This is what gets displayed in Chrome

[image]

How can I fix the problem with the way the background is rendered in Chrome while minimising duplication of CSS rules?

Comment: It works fine for me in Chrome 17.0.963.56 m (using the -webkit- prefix)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `:before` pseudo-class for your background icons.

```
.img1:before {
  content: '';
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  background: transparent url('img1.png') left top no-repeat;
  width: 16px; /* change to actual width of img */
  height: 16px; /* change to actual height of img */
}
```

Or, since you're trying to relieve the amount of CSS, you can specify a class for the gradient and append that in your HTML.

Comment: I'm hoping I don't need to use that much CSS just to specify a different background image for each heading

Comment: Specify a class for your gradient. Append that class in your HTML.

Comment: @juanrpozo You need to specify the height of the parent: `.bgImage { height: 48px; }`

Comment: This solution uses a more terse CSS sheet: http://jsfiddle.net/jcBDn/ - Also floats degrade much better.

Comment: @juanrpozo if you post that as an answer, I'll accept it and award you the bounty

Comment: @Don it was actually Nick's idea, I was just curious to see it in action, that's why I posted it as a comment.

Answer (score 4):

Don, you have two classes which this background gradient can be applied to, `bgImage` and `banner`. Simply apply your gradient on to one of those classes and go from there. Also append `repeat-x` right after your image url to ensure it will repeat across.